# Convergence of the series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^nx)$

Tags: analysis

What about the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\sin(2^nx)$??

Here $x$ is any fixed real number.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like x must be in a form

$x = k\pi$, where k - integer

Some hint that should help: it's easy to prove that for small enough $\epsilon$: $\frac{1}{1000} > \epsilon > 0$ and for any y: $ 0 < y < \epsilon $ we can find natural m such that $sin(2^my) > \frac{1}{10}$